# how to send transactional emails using mailchimp

Tags: mailchimp, mandrill

I am new to Mail chimp please help me to integrate transnational Emails using mail chimp and 
mandrill.Better to provider example with integration code.

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide more information. What are you trying to do? What programming language are you using? Have you looked at the [API documentation](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't mention what you are actually trying to achieve.

In general, you don't want to use Mailchimp for this - you want to just focus on Mandrill.

Mailchimp is for when you have an existing list of users and you want to send emails to some or all of them at the same time - such as newsletters.

Mandrill is for when you need to send one user (or a small group of users) occasional emails for notification purposes - such as alerts, receipts, acknowledgements, etc.

Assuming you have an application which already sends emails to users via SMTP, you can easily integrate Mandrill by simply changing the SMTP server settings in your application to use the Mandrill SMTP settings, which you can find at the top of the [SMTP & API Credentials](https://mandrillapp.com/settings/index) page in your Mandrill admin area.

Alternatively, if you need to send programatically, refer to the documentation on [API Wrappers](http://mandrill.zendesk.com/entries/21738166-API-Wrappers) to get you started.